# How to set htaccess to redirect/rewrite from to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want htp://www.seostuff.org.ua/?s=seo to be redirected to htp://seo.seostuff.org.ua

Instead of seo can be any other search pattern

Buy this way I managed to make htp://seo.seostuff.org.ua redirecting to htp://www.seostuff.org.ua/?s=seo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.seostuff\.org\.ua
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.seostuff\.org\.ua [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.seostuff\.org\.ua/?s=%1 [L]
```

But I do not want URL change it should stay the same, ex htp://seo.seostuff.org.ua
I want revert requests to be processed as well (means htp://www.seostuff.org.ua/?s=seo should 301 redirect to htp://seo.seostuff.org.ua)

Also I do not need any slowness of processing such URL requests. Want to create optimized Rules. Any help please?

I would really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rewrite to a full HTTP URL without redirect to it.

So try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite abc.seostuff.org.ua to abc.seostuff.org.ua/?s=abc
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.seostuff.org.ua
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).seostuff.org.ua
RewriteRule .* ?s=%1 [L]
# redirect seostuff.org.ua/?s=abc to abc.seostuff.org.ua
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1.seostuff.org.ua/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works but leaves 
http://test.seostuff.org.ua/?s=test 
instead  http://test.seostuff.org.ua/


May be add some condiotion?>

Comment: Although this is probably due wordpress internal php rules

Comment: Nope... now it says about redirect loop((

It looks like the previous rules were correct... just problem with last redirect